# Using Appium unable to swipe from the bottom to the top to open control centre with iOS 15

Tags: java, ios, appium, appium-ios

I would like to open the iOS control centre (to activate airplane mode) using **appium 1.22 with iOS 15.1**. The code I am using works great with **iOS 14.8**. I have tried using TouchAction and PointerInput Actions, with the same result. The screen scrolls up on 15.1 but the control centre does not appear. Any help would be appreciated, I am blocked with automated tests on iOS 15.

Environment:
iOS 15
appium 1.22

My code:

```
        Dimension d = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int width = d.getWidth();
        int height = d.getHeight();

        int w = (int) (.5 * width);
        int swipeTo = (int) (height * 0.2);

        PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
        Sequence swipeUpForControlCentre = new Sequence(finger, 1);
        swipeUpForControlCentre.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), w, height));
        swipeUpForControlCentre.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(0));
        swipeUpForControlCentre.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(700),
                PointerInput.Origin.viewport(),w, swipeTo));
        swipeUpForControlCentre.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(0));
        driver.perform(Arrays.asList(swipeUpForControlCentre));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is using driver.activateApp() to switch to iOS Settings App, and switching back to the app I'm testing afterwards. So problem is at least not blocking me anymore. I liked using the control center for various things. Oh well ...